# Can Relay's RefetchContainer update sibling components with a refetch?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relaymodern

Is it possible to update the props of a component by calling `refetch` from a sibling component?

Consider components with the following structure:

```
<Home> # wrapped in a QueryRenderer
    <List /> # wrapped in a Fragment Container
    <Map /> # wrapped in a Refetch Container
</Home>
```

`List` and `Map` use the same query endpoint: `allItems`.

When `Map` calls `refetch`, it's own data updates, `List`'s data does not update, however.

The refetch query is identical to the `Home`'s `QueryRenderer` query. It appears that Relay does not map the result of the refetch to the parts of the store that hold the data for `List`, as `List`'s props do not change.

Is it possible for a refetch to update props outside of component the Refetch Container contains? If not, how can changes in one component fire a refetch and update the props of a sibling component without moving the refetch container to a higher level - unless this is the only way?

For some more context, I've included some code to illustrate the structure and queries more clearly.

Using Relay, suppose we have a parent component wrapped in a `QueryRenderer` to perform an initial data fetch.

```
        <QueryRenderer
            environment={environment}
            query={graphql`
                query HomeQuery {
                    ...List_query
                    ...Map_query
                }
            `}
            render={({ error, props }) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    return <div>Error!</div>
                }
                if (!props) {
                    return <div>Loading...</div>
                }

                return (
                    <div>
                        <List query={props} />
                        <Map query={props} />
                    </div>
                )
            }}
        />
```

Both `List` and `Map` contain fragments. `List` is wrapped with a Fragment Container:

```
createFragmentContainer(List, {
    query: graphql`
        fragment List_query on Query {
            allItems(first: 10) @connection(key: "Map_allItems") {
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `
})
```

Whereas the `Map` is wrapped in a Refetch Container:

```
createRefetchContainer(
    Map,
    {
        query: graphql`
            fragment Map_query on Query {
                allItems(first: 10) @connection( key: "Map_allItems") {
                    edges {
                        node {
                            id
                            name
                            created
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        `
    },
    graphql`
        query MapRefetchQuery {
            ...Map_query
            ...List_query
        }
    `
)
```

The code has been reduced, so may have a typo in it! Let me know if this is the case, and I'll update it.

Comment: You should move the refetch container up. Relay containers act like HOCs (so really just another React component), so you should not expect a container to cause side-effects in sibling containers. Doing so is likely possible, but imho it won't be semantic, and will be very ugly.